# How to implement a Converter in ReactiveUI?

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

Can someone help clarify how to properly use IBindingTypeConverters.

I declared a converter called FromPromptTypeToValueConverter. I would like to use it in one specific case by passing in two parameters:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
    vm => vm.PopupType,
    view => view.ButtonOk.IsVisible,
    new FromPromptTypeToValueConverter(OkValue: true, YesNoValue: false))
.DisposeWith(disposable);
```

But an error occurs which REQUIRES me to register the converter in the bootstrapping code. But I don't want that because I end up with two instances of the Converter (one is created in the bootstrapping Registration and the other one directly in the binding).

Is there any way to use the converter with Registering it??  I guess my question is also, "Why register a converter if I only need to use it in one spot?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you only need to perform the conversion in one spot then you're better off just providing the conversion logic *in situ*:

```
this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Property, x => x.target, value => /* do conversion here */);
```

However, if you want to use a converter you can:

```
this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, x => x.Property, x => x.target, vmToViewConverterOverride: /* converter instance here */);
```

Notice the argument name being qualified. The problem with your existing code is the converter you create is being passed as the optional `conversionHint` argument.

Comment: What about async conversion due IO, like in XAML IsAsync=true?